# Maximum tolerance for a loop trace-antenna's capacitor

Tags: capacitance, transmitter, pcb-antenna, tolerance, loss

While going through the document at https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN639.pdf I have read from "Figure 13. Loop Antenna Simulated Mag(Zin) vs. CP1" below that even a 2% tolerance for Cp1 results in a Zin of about 200 - 250 Ohm for the 434 MHz frequency range that I am heading for. The desired Zin is 500 Ohm.

I am not sure if this is the case but as I understand it this will cause a good fraction of the power to be reflected back into the IC. If so, could I have a maximum tolerance level for Cp1 so that my transmitter will not require full power in order to cover a mere few meters ? (in ohter words, for my transmitter not to perform poorly)

[image]

Comment: anytime Q=350, component tolerance on f and Zin is going to be very tight.  as it is inverse to the Q.  Dont forget dielectric tolerance of 10% ...  go for the 55mm square and 15dB return loss and work out the tolerances.  Otherwise, just use a 1/4 lambda wire. which will work for that range and tune length

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Ok, is the dielectric with the 10% tolerance the PCB's dielectric ? If it is, isn't most of the electrical field radiated by this antenna formed between its two sides of the loop, so air would be the dielectric ? What is a '55 mm square' ?

Comment: FR4 is inside the loop and this also affects self resonant freq.  with e~4 +-10% . Datasheet shows dBi gain is max for 55mm square loop  -3dBi ? as I recall, which is an indication of losses.  Coupling to free space impedance affects far field levels with air as a diectric.  The velocity factor for tuning L of V.F. 0.82 is prrof of this interaction.

Comment: Don't expect to find a standard-size capacitor to tune this structure without having to add some PCB trim capacitance. As the app-note (and Tony) imply: calculate, build, measure....probably will take more than a few iterations.

Comment: Okay, thanks you both,but I am not going to go through all the theory and test iterations. I shall stick with the given design which has all been set up optimally. My question was related to that final tuning cap Cp1. Let me rephrase it: How much power will I lose if instead the optimum 500 Ohm impedance I ended up with a 250 Ohm impedance ? How would I calculate that ?

Answer (score 1):

[image: ente image description here]

Here a 55mm square loop gives the highest gain using 0.8mm FR4

Reducing area 50% correlates with ~3dB loss each time from this.

The author's calculation of v.f.= 0.82c is an indication of FR4 dielectric effects on wavelength and C values required.

Contrary to what the author says, the shunt capacitance controls a parallel resonant pole and not the series zero.

***[Here](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.5%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%205%20495225953.23642385%0AO%20320%20160%20320%2096%200%0Ag%20384%20208%20384%20224%200%0Ar%20352%20208%20384%20208%200%201%0Al%20240%20160%20288%20160%200%201.0264000000000001e-7%200%0A170%20240%20160%20208%20160%203%2020%201000%205%200.1%0Ar%20320%20160%20288%20160%200%201%0Ac%20352%20160%20320%20160%200%201.3099999999999999e-12%200%0Ac%20240%20160%20240%20208%200%201e-11%200%0Aw%20352%20160%20352%20208%200%0Aw%20416%20208%20240%20208%200%0Ao%204%2016%200%2034%205%200.00009765625%200%20-1%0Ao%200%2016%200%2034%205%200.00009765625%201%20-1%0A)*** is my simulation.
[image]

You can play with the values and aim at peak to get a reading. Note how phase changes abruptly at series resonance.

THe 1 Ohm ground shunt measures current and the Out before the cap measure transfer function while moving out to the 1 Ohm measures Zin.  Q here is about 320 or 42.73dB gain limited by Series ESR and sense R ratio as well as X(f) for a crude approximation... set to 434 MHz.

***[Here](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.5%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%205%20585886777.1868712%0AO%20352%20128%20352%2064%200%0Ag%20384%20176%20384%20192%200%0Ar%20352%20176%20384%20176%200%201%0Al%20240%20128%20288%20128%200%201.0264000000000001e-7%200%0A170%20240%20128%20208%20128%203%2020%201000%205%200.1%0Ar%20320%20128%20288%20128%200%200.1%0Ac%20352%20128%20320%20128%200%201.3099999999999999e-12%200%0Ac%20240%20128%20240%20176%200%201.4999999999999997e-11%200%0Aw%20352%20128%20352%20176%200%0Aw%20352%20176%20240%20176%200%0Ao%204%2016%200%2034%205%200.00009765625%200%20-1%0Ao%200%2016%200%2034%205%200.00009765625%201%20-1%0A)*** showing the effects of a shunt C with a notch in radiated power by parallel resonance which comes closer to series f with larger C values.

[image]